# Searching for value in multiple arrays contained in an object (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, find

I have a JSON file, structured like this:

```
{
  "greetings": {
    "question": [
      "Hello",
      "Good Morning"
    ],
    "answers": [
      "Hello there",
      "Good Morning to you too"
    ]
  },
  "goodbyes": {
    "question": [
      "goodbye",
      "see you soon"
    ],
    "answers": [
      "Goodbye dear",
      "not if I see you first"
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to find a value in both of the arrays "question". So for example, if I have

```
let i = "Hello"
```

How can I find out that *i* is contained in "greetings"?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few built-in JavaScript methods that make this task easy:

- [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) - extract all the property values of an object to an array
- [Array.prototype.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)() - flatten an array
- [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) - join array items into a string
- [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) - is search string contained in another string?

These can be chained together to answer the question:

> Does the `greetings` object contain the string "Hello"?

Put into action:

```js
const data = {
  "greetings": {
    "question": [
      "Hello",
      "Good Morning"
    ],
    "answers": [
      "Hello there",
      "Good Morning to you too"
    ]
  },
  "goodbyes": {
    "question": [
      "goodbye",
      "see you soon"
    ],
    "answers": [
      "Goodbye dear",
      "not if I see you first"
    ]
  }
};

const greetingsHasHello = Object.values(data.greetings)
  .flat()
  .join('')
  .includes('Hello');
  
console.log(`greetings has "Hello":`, greetingsHasHello);
```